# For the given matrix $A$, find an invertible matrix $D$ such that $D^{-1}AD = J_A$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose the matrix $A$ is the following matrix:

\begin{pmatrix}
-2 & 0 & 0\\
-1 & 1 & 3 \\
2 & 3 & 1
\end{pmatrix}

I found my characteristic and minimal polynomial of $A$ to be $\chi(t) = (4-t)(t+2)^2$ and my Jordan canonical form to be

\begin{pmatrix}
4 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -2 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & -2
\end{pmatrix}

I found my eigenvectors to be $v_1 = (0, 1, 1)$ corresponding to eigenvalue $4$ and $v_2 = (0, -1, 1)$ corresponding to eigenvalue $-2$.  I need to find a third eigenvector $v_3$ for eigenvalue $-2$ and then I can let $D = (v_1^T, v_2^T, v_3^T)$.  Now, the third column of my Jordan matrix is telling me that:

$Av_3 = v_2 + -2v_3$

But, if I let $v_3 = (x, y, z)$ and plug it into the equation, it leads to the following system which has no solution:

$-2x = -2x$

$-x + y + 3z = -1 - 2y$

$2x + 3y + z = 1 - 2z$

If I let $x = 1$ for simplicity, it reduces to:

$3y + 3z = 0$

$3y + 3z = -1$

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing wrong is choosing the value of $x$. If you don't, you get the system,
\begin{align*}
-x + 3y + 3z &= -1 \\
2x + 3y + 3z &= 1
\end{align*}
Note that the $3y + 3z$ can be absorbed into a single variable, let's say $w$, and we get a system
\begin{align*}
-x + w &= -1 \\
2x + w &= 1
\end{align*}
with a unique solution $x = 2/3$, $w = 3y + 3z = -1/3$. Then either $y$ or $z$ can be chosen freely, and the other will have its value determined. But, you may not choose the value of $x$! It must be $2/3$, or there will be no solution.